# Export WordPress database table to excel file with all meta informations

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I try to export an Excel file from a WordPress database `users` table. It works in general. But I also need to add all user_meta data into this file. How could I combine this?

**My code:**

```
<?php
//Include the wp-load.php file
include('../../../../wp-load.php');
//As this is external file, we aren't using the WP theme here. So setting this as false
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
$file = 'email_csv'; // ?? not defined in original code
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name", ARRAY_A);

if (empty($results)) {
    return;
}

$csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_keys($results[0])).'";'."\n";;

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"',$row).'";'."\n";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

Comment: The thing is: you cannot fit a 1:n-relation into a CSV. Plus, `user_meta` doesn't have a fixed key-value count per user. I don't see any logical way of fitting this into a single CSV file. If it's only about a couple of meta_keys with a predefined name, it's possible to append columns to the right. Other than that, a separate CSV file would probably make more sense.

Comment: The meta values are the most important for me. There I save data like `company`, `firstname`, `address` and other values. Would be great to save only this to a CSV file.. would be okay to create manually a custom predefined name. Do you have an idea to create something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your custom list of meta_keys (`company`, `firstname`, `address`) you can define an array containing these, and add them to the CSV as trailing columns like so:

```
global $wpdb;

// Define your custom meta keys you want to add as columns HERE:
$meta_keys = ['company', 'firstname', `address`]; // can contain as many as you want

// This function will load the desired keys as an associative array
// in the form: [$meta_key_1 => $meta_value_1, ..., $meta_key_n => $meta_value_n]
function load_user_meta($user_id, $keys) {
    $meta_row = [];
    foreach ($keys as $meta_key) {
        $value = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, true);
        $meta_row[$meta_key] = $value;
    }
    return $meta_row;
}

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name", ARRAY_A);

if (empty($results)) {
    return;
}

// Merge the result's keys with the list of custom meta keys:
$csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_merge(array_keys($results[0]), $meta_keys )).'";'."\n";

foreach ($results as $row) {
    // load the custom meta for this user's ID:
    $custom_meta_row = load_user_meta($row['ID'], $meta_keys);
    // merge the acquired user meta into the row output:
    $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"',array_merge($row, $custom_meta_row)).'";'."\n";
}

$csv_output .= "\n";
```

If a certain `meta_key` does not exist for all users, this still works since `get_user_meta` will produce an empty string for these cases.

Additional note: it's generally not a good idea to produce CSV output the way you do. This works as long as there are no `"` and `;` characters anywhere in your `user_meta` - those characters would have to be escaped with a certain escape character. Therefore, it is better to use `fputcsv` on the output stream (  `$outstream = fopen("php://output", 'w');`).